# Is there a way in the GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am trying to create a programm to confirm pregnancy with a hormone level(GCH it is a int parameter of a diccionary), but in the GUI I get this error:
"if examen["GCH"] >= 9 and examen["genero"] == F:"
TypeError: string indices must be integers

MAIN:

```
def confirm_pregnancy(exam: dict) -> bool:
 if exam ["GCH"]>= 9 and exam ["gender"] == F:
     pregnancy = True
 else:
     pregnancy = False
 return pregnancy
```

GUI:

```
def execute_confirm_pregnancy (e1: dict, e2: dict, e3: dict, e4: dict) -> None:

 "" "
 It executes the function that validates if there is pregnancy depending on the levels of HCG in the blood test with
 id given by parameter
  Parameters: e
     e1 (dict): Dictionary with information from exam 1.
     e2 (dict): Dictionary with information from exam 2.
     e3 (dict): Dictionary with the information of the exam 3.
     e4 (dict): Dictionary with the information of the exam 4.
 The program should show the user: "Test results suggest that the patient is pregnant." if he
 Exam confirms it. Otherwise, the message is expected to be: "Test results suggest that the patient is NOT pregnant."
 "" "

 id = input ("Enter the identifier of the patient you want to search for")
 print (mod.confirm_pregnancy (id))
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the error message.  It's not obvious here where an index ito a string is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are doing here is passing the wrong type of argument to `confirm_pregnancy(exam: dict)` function, where you are passing a string instead of dictionary.

at GUI part of your code in the function `execute_confirm_pregnancy` you use The `input` function which is a `built-in` function reads a line from standard input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

if we execute your line of code:
`id = input("Enter the identifier of the patient you want to search for")`, the program will prompt to us:

> Enter the identifier of the patient you want to search for

**anything** that the user of the program will enter will returned as a string and stored in the `id` variable, if we assume that the user will enter for example: `GCH 9 gender F`, then `id = 'GCH 9 gender F'` which is a string (array of chars)

when you call `confirm_pregnancy(id)` with `id` as an argument of `string type` to this function you try to treat a string (array of chars) as dictionary of key value pairs, so when function try to locate the value of `id['GCH']` it will raise a `TypeError` because `id` is a `list of chars` which indexed with integer incidences, i.e `id[0] = G, id[1] = C, etc .., but` not a `key` like dict.

you should to parse your user input and store it as a dict type rather than a string.

your question is not so clear about how the dictionary look like and how many key value pairs it contains, so that the answer could not be straight about how to parse the input from the user and store it in dict.